# Delete file from tar in python without rewriting

Tags: python-3.x, compression, tar

I want to delete a file in a tarfile that is compressed.
My project is in python 3 but i found a project called [pyNMS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pynms/) for python 2 but i didn't get it to work even witha old version of python 2.
My endgoal is to add extra information to a tar file that can be changed without rewrites of a 1GB or bigger tar file.
The info file gets added after the file is written so it is at the end of the tar but the tar later gets password protected so i can't just remove everything after the filename with .split()

Comment: I am not sure this is possible with a TAR format. TAR is a stream-based archive that doesn't support random access inside the archive itself. It's a forward iterator. The options are: use a different archive, like ZIP, or read-modify-write into a separate tar file (which is a copy operation).

Comment: It is the last file so no moving but pass protected. But thank you for you suggestion of zip does it support randown write/read ? AND Password protection. Eventhough i would have liked tar support for my project.

Comment: First you say you want to delete a file in a tar file (where?), then you say you want to append to a tar file? And then it's encrypted? How? You need to describe exactly what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Re tar, it's a stream of bytes. There is some structure to it, but it is minimal. There is a small header in front of a file followed by file byte content. To get to the last file, you will need to read the full archive. Re protection, it's a separate question. You can use password protection on Zip, but the algorithm and portability may be limited. You could encrypt the file manually before adding it to a Zip archive.

Comment: Re-reading the question, you could try separating meta info (that you want to change) from the file content itself (this won't be modified). Store file info in a separate file, which is easy and fast to modify. Large files are stored next (or in a separate dir/database/whatever).

Comment: Sorry for confusion i already can append to a tar file. But good point with the seperation is there a way to merge a txt file next to a tar file(it does not need to be accessable by the user) without the tar losing its funktion like a hidden txt in a picture?

Comment: I still can't make any sense out of what you're saying. A "good point"? "merge" something "next to" something?? The file is hidden somehow??? You need to give an explicit and clear example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [tar](/questions/tagged/tar) command is not like **zip**.

There is no option for defining/using a password to protect the contents.

If the file is encrypted, that is a different tool, not tar.

You cannot manipulate the tar contents while encrypted.  You must first decrypt, then perform any necessary operations using basic tar functionality.

So ... if your desire was to avoid manipulating GBs of data, limiting that to only MBs of data, via "injection" of a content delta, that is not possible.

**NOTE:**  This next idea may not be within the scope of your problem, but it may provide the optimal solution.

If you created a partition dedicated to that content, **then had that partition encrypted by default**, you could then store your tar file **in the clear**, **without encryption**.  This would allow you to perform all actions on the tar file directly, in the manner that you were hoping for, if the environment would allow you to cope with accessing an encrypted filesystem on the fly.

Also, if not a fully-dedicated partition, you could create **an encrypted file which could act as a partition**.  [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58935/how-do-i-create-an-encrypted-filesystem-inside-a-file) posting addresses that scenario.